# Selenium Webdriver getting a cookie value

Tags: ruby, automation, webdriver, cucumber, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get a cookie value but keep getting an error of `<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x13a0e0e8 browser=:firefox>`

I am calling

```
@browser.cookie_named("configsession").each do |cookie|
  puts cookie[:name]
```

is there something I i'm doing wrong?

Comment: give us the full error stack and codes as much as relevant..

Comment: Have you navigated to a URL before trying to get cookies from the browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods for working with cookies are defined in the Selenium::WebDriver::Options - see the [API docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Options.html).

To access these cookie methods, you need to call the `manage` method for the driver:

```
@browser.manage
```

To get a cookie based on its name, you need to do:

```
@browser.manage.cookie_named("configsession")
```

Note that `cookie_named` returns a single cookie that matches. The cookies values are a hash. Therefore, you can get values of the cookie by doing:

```
cookie = @browser.manage.cookie_named("configsession")
cookie[:name]
#=> "configsession"
```

If you want to get the name of all the cookies on the page, use the `all_cookies` method:

```
driver.manage.all_cookies.each do |cookie|
    puts cookie[:name]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Cookie cookie= driver.manage().getCookieNamed("sitename.session");  
String cookieVal= cookie.getValue();
```

Comment: Which programming language is this? Given that the question is tagged with 'ruby', it would be better to give an answer written in Ruby.

Comment: You are right, this is not ruby but java. But this reply helped me :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    Set<Cookie> cook =  driver.manage().getCookies();
    for(Cookie cooks : cook) 
    {

    System.out.println(cooks.getName());
    }

    Cookie t = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("_gid");
    if(t!=null){
    String s1 = t.getValue();
    System.out.println("The Cookie value is : " + s1);
               }
```